# Inline HTML Angular Nested Quotes

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been building a popover to pull in an image as its content. The conflict is the multi-layer quotes. Other posts have suggested javascript solutions. Unfortunately, those aren't an option due to server script limitations. How do I make these inline quotes work? I've tried it several ways, none of them have been working.

```
<div uib-popover-html="'<img src="*image_location*" />'">
<div uib-popover-html="'<img src='*image_location*' />'">
<div uib-popover-html="'<img src=`*image_location*` />'">
```

this is the required format of the angular binding:

```
<div uib-popover-html="'<*inline html elements go here*>'">
```

All is well prior to specifying a location of the image.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In sharepoint world i used html encoding? 
&apos;&lt;img src=&grave;*image_location*&grave; /&gt;&apos;

Comment: Did you try to escape character (`\'`, `\"`)?

Comment: I tried the escape characters, but they still don't pass the location of the image.

@dotsa
it's not necessarily a symbol encoding issue.
The img tag won't allow for other characters such as single quote to designate the location, it'll only allow for double quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your server script limitations but they are letting you use angular? I'm assuming(perhaps incorrectly) that you have at least some angular app and controller. It really  looks like UIB's documentation requires the $sce be injected in the ctrl and you set a $scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<img src="*image_location*" />'); $sce looks like angular core .. if you can use a controller with scope maybe you can use that ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce . Sorry if I'm mentioning something that you already ruled out

Comment: @Tom22
this was kind of the only way to go, it's a more complicated way to go about it, I was really trying to avoid a controller if at all possible. One of the backend guys wrote a controller though.